# Specifying jQuery dialog size in ems?

Tags: jquery-ui, dialog

Is there any way to specify a jQuery dialog size in ems?  The dialog I'll be displaying will be modal, and non-resizable, so resizing isn't an issue.  It should just stick at the size I initially specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of specifying the width directly in the dialog call, I think the best way to get the jQuery dialog to a certain height and width in ems is to actually specify the size of the content, then use `'auto'` to make the dialog size itself to the content.  Here's an example which uses 60em and 30em as the max width and height:

```
<span id="copyrightLink" style="cursor:pointer;">Copyright dialog popup</span>

<div id="copyrightDialog" title="Copyright information" style="display:none;">
    <div style="max-width:60em; max-height:30em;">
        <p>Copyright information</p>
        <p>Goes here</p>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#copyrightLink').click(function(){
            $('#copyrightDialog').dialog({
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    OK: function(){
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                },
                width: 'auto',
                height: 'auto',
                resizable: false,
                draggable: false
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't set a start size via the `dialog(...)` set the dialog size via css and it will be that way to begin with.

See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/cQBTb/

Javascript:

```
$('selector').dialog({
    width: '17em',
    resizable: false,
    modal: true
});​
```

CSS:

```
selector {
    height: 15em !important;
}​
```

Comment: @Jez see the demo in my answer.

Comment: `width: '17em'` seems to be undocumented, so I'm not sure I want to risk using that.

Comment: @Jez all `width` in the dialog function does is set the css width of the dialog. It is `height` that does not do anything, therefor you need to set it via CSS

Comment: According to [this bug](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5663), the width option "was not meant to be used" with ems.